# In pandas, how can I find the count of each variable combination from 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns of data `pox` and `sex` containing boolean values of 1 and 2.
I am trying to get out of this 4 different values, males who did and did not get chicken pox, as well as females who did and did not get chicken pox.

First in my mind, this method made sense

```
male_pos = len(df_pox.loc[df_pox['pox']==1 & df_pox['SEX']==1])
male_neg = len(df_pox.loc[df_pox['pox']==2 & df_pox['SEX']==1])
```

...but I got an error saying that the result was ambiguous.

Then I thought I could try grouping by sex and pulling out the value that way

```
male_pos = df_pox.groupby(['SEX']==1)[['pox']==1].count()
```

...but I was thrown a big error that just ended in False

A possible result popped up when I was submitting this and it showed a method using a list, but it also used the loc() function, which I think I will end up running into the same problem as my first attempt.

I would like to get an int value from the DataFrame for each of the values:
`male_pos`
`male_neg`
`female_pos`
`female_neg`

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: You need to provide a MRE. In the meantime, you could check `df_pox.groupby(['SEX', 'pox']).size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea was right, you were just missing parentheses to clarify the order of operations in your condition.

```py
male_pos = len(df_pox.loc[(df_pox['pox'] == 1) & (df_pox['SEX'] == 1)])
```

This will give you the expected output.

Comment: That did it.  I thought I had the right idea and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.  Thanks for that!